# How to count the reads on index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, query

I have a table with index.

```sql
CREATE TABLE PART  ( P_PARTKEY     INTEGER NOT NULL,
                          P_NAME        VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
                          P_MFGR        CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
                          P_BRAND       CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                          P_TYPE        VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
                          P_SIZE        INTEGER NOT NULL,
                          P_CONTAINER   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                          P_RETAILPRICE DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL,
                          P_COMMENT     VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL );

CREATE TABLE LINEITEM ( L_ORDERKEY    INTEGER NOT NULL,
                             L_PARTKEY     INTEGER NOT NULL,
                             L_SUPPKEY     INTEGER NOT NULL,
                             L_LINENUMBER  INTEGER NOT NULL,
                             L_QUANTITY    DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL,
                             L_EXTENDEDPRICE  DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL,
                             L_DISCOUNT    DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL,
                             L_TAX         DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL,
                             L_RETURNFLAG  CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
                             L_LINESTATUS  CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
                             L_SHIPDATE    DATE NOT NULL,
                             L_COMMITDATE  DATE NOT NULL,
                             L_RECEIPTDATE DATE NOT NULL,
                             L_SHIPINSTRUCT CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
                             L_SHIPMODE     CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                             L_COMMENT      VARCHAR(44) NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE LINEITEM
ADD PRIMARY KEY (L_ORDERKEY,L_LINENUMBER);

ALTER TABLE PART
ADD PRIMARY KEY (P_PARTKEY);
```

And query

```sql
SELECT Sum(l_extendedprice * ( 1 - l_discount )) AS revenue
FROM   lineitem,
       part
WHERE  ( p_partkey = l_partkey
         AND p_brand = 'Brand#52'
         AND p_container IN ( 'SM CASE', 'SM BOX', 'SM PACK', 'SM PKG' )
         AND l_quantity >= 4
         AND l_quantity <= 4 + 10
         AND p_size BETWEEN 1 AND 5
         AND l_shipmode IN ( 'AIR', 'AIR REG' )
         AND l_shipinstruct = 'DELIVER IN PERSON' )
        OR ( p_partkey = l_partkey
             AND p_brand = 'Brand#11'
             AND p_container IN ( 'MED BAG', 'MED BOX', 'MED PKG', 'MED PACK' )
             AND l_quantity >= 18
             AND l_quantity <= 18 + 10
             AND p_size BETWEEN 1 AND 10
             AND l_shipmode IN ( 'AIR', 'AIR REG' )
             AND l_shipinstruct = 'DELIVER IN PERSON' )
        OR ( p_partkey = l_partkey
             AND p_brand = 'Brand#51'
             AND p_container IN ( 'LG CASE', 'LG BOX', 'LG PACK', 'LG PKG' )
             AND l_quantity >= 29
             AND l_quantity <= 29 + 10
             AND p_size BETWEEN 1 AND 15
             AND l_shipmode IN ( 'AIR', 'AIR REG' )
             AND l_shipinstruct = 'DELIVER IN PERSON' );
```

I want to know

- how many reads are performed on index.
- how many reads are performed on table data.
- how many index are in the buffer (memory) and in the disk.
- how many table data are in the buffer (memory) and in the disk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Metrics**

It is possible to find the number of rows looked at in the tables for a single query.  These count rows of index or data, not counted separately, for your connection.  If no other queries are running, total counts are possible.

```
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Here is a discussion of using that to help with optimization: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

From

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_%';
```

you can get certain global counts for disk accesses, etc. for all InnoDB statements from all connections.  (This is not precisely what you are asking for, but may be interesting.)

Another source is the system database `performance_schema`.  (In older MySQL versions, `information_schema` had some tables, but there are mostly moved to PS now.)

If you elaborate on the *goals* of your question, we might be able to help in more detail.

**Optimizing that query**

Start by using the modern `JOIN` syntax:

```
FROM lineitem AS l
JOIN part AS p  ON p.partkey = l.partkey
```

That was a common part of the ORs; this makes it so the Optimizer can do the JOIN more efficiently.

In case the Optimizer decides to start with `part`, have this

```
lineitem:  INDEX(partkey)  -- (but see below)
```

Now I see that `l.shipinstruct = 'DELIVER IN PERSON'` is common across the ORs, so pull it out.  Then this would probably be useful

```
lineitem:  INDEX(shipinstruct)  -- (but see below)
```

But, all of that probably still won't do as much Optimization as turning the `OR` into `UNION ALL`:

```
( SELECT ... Brand#52 ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... Brand#11 ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... Brand#51 ... )
```

Then we can build some even better indexes:

```
part:  INDEX(brand, container)
part:  INDEX(brand, size)
lineitem:  INDEX(shipinstruct, quantity)
lineitem:  INDEX(shipinstruct, shipmode)
lineitem:  INDEX(partkey, shipinstruct, quantity)
lineitem:  INDEX(partkey, shipinstruct, shipmode)
```

There are many ways the Optimizer might pick to run the query; I think these cover all the bases.